# Serial port ignoring custom divisor

Tags: linux, android, serial-port

I am trying to run a serial port at 3.25Mb/s by applying a divisor of 2 to a baud base of 6.5Mb/s. I am using an IoT device (Telit HE922-3GR) running android 6 with built in serial ports, the `proc/tty/driver/ttyS` file contains:

```
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:XGOLD_USIF mmio:0xE1200000 irq:36 tx:32497 rx:20751 fe:1834 RTS|DTR|DSR|CD|RI
1: uart:XGOLD_USIF mmio:0xE1100000 irq:35 tx:453 rx:0 RTS|DTR|DSR|CD|RI
```

I am using /dev/ttyS1

The divisor is being set in `sys/class/tty/ttyS0/custom_divisor` to the correct value but the serial port is still running at 6.5Mb/s, no matter what the divisor.

Is there anything I can do to ensure the serial port uses this divisor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a closer look at the broadcom datasheet specs of some iOT chipsets, you will see there white in black, that the serial communication services implementation in ARM iOT are partial **emulations** of the common 16550 serial chipsets you find commonly in the PC world. As far as I remember, they write explicitly the emulation only suports a small subset of the 16550 services.

So they provide only a good enough subset of the services "full blown UARTs" provide.

Bottom line, do not count on it supporting all the usual functionalities at 100%.

Comment: Might be worth noting that it can run at other non standard baud rate like 3Mb/s and 3.5Mb/s using constants defined in termios.h, would the port not need to use a divisor to achieve those speeds?

Comment: I suspect it has some "official" speeds built-in...cannot neither remember the full docs, nor having the time today to search and read them.